# Find/Replace disabled in word 2007 document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have a form that someone created and sent to me. I am opening it in Word 2007.

It seems like the form is editable - i have no problem filling out the fields and saving the document. However, the  Find/Replace options are greyed out/disabled. I checked the protection on the document and it is set to unrestricted. What is causing find/replace to be disabled?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restricting and locking are two different things, so it is possible the document is not restricted but just needs to be unlocked. Forms typically don't work properly unless they are locked.

Check the Review tab and then on the Restrict Formatting and Editing, an Unprotect option should be available.

Comment: It seems to be asking me for a password when I click on "Stop Protecting." Do you know what password this is, or how I can get a non-password version of this file (save-as or something?)

Comment: The password is used to protect the document from being changed. Obviously the person who developed the form doesn't want anyone doing that. A "save as" will not remove protection. You will have to contact the person who developed the form to ask for the password.